# Impedance for a communications console

Tags: audio, impedance-matching

I'm working on some old school Zetron consoles for my summer job.  They provide 2/4 wireline control to some base radios as well as I/O for aux operations like triggering relays to open/close doors and turn lights on/off.

Generally they get installed in sets of two(2) or more.  When installed together one of them needs to have an impedance jumper set to high impedance while the other is set to low.  If you have more than two(2) then the farthest one from the base stations is set to low impedance while the others are set to high.

I understand that the setting of the high impedance is so it doesn't load the audio on the system and make it weak but my question is why don't we just set them ALL to high impedance?  What does the single low impedance unit do to the system?  What disadvantage is there to having them all be set to high impedance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is half guess: -

By the sound of it, the unit can broadcast audio and send control data over many hundreds of metres. If so, data/control will be some form of digital signalling and without a proper terminator at the end of a long run of cable you will possible get data corruptions. This is my gut feeling.

RS485 is a data system that needs exactly the same not because of some quirk in its design but because of the laws of physics requires data terminators for long runs of data.

It looks like Zetron are still making good stuff in this area so if you have a product name or code then a link would be useful to anyone wanting to look technically deeper into this.

Comment: Doh!  Yeah, that makes sense now.  Gotta remember my transmission line theory.  Thanks for shaking the cob webs out of my head.